# What is the name of this tiny creature?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Place: South India,

Metropolitan, Year: 2017; Night Time.

Size: 1-2 cm (Very Tiny)

[image]

Comment: Looks like a moth.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's 'Indian skipper'. Family :Hesperiidae.
Source: http://abeautiful-butterflys.blogspot.in/2010/04/hesperiidae-butterflies-of-india.html

Comment: This is not a skipper. Skippers are bigger, have a different shaped body and a different wing pattern, as can be seen from your picture.

Answer (score 0):

From the posture, it looks like it can belong to Geometridae (Larentiinae). But I haven't been able to find a species that has that particular color.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely a moth; possible families are **Pyralidae**, **Crambidae**, or **Thyrididae** (**Window-Winged Moths**); the first two listed (**Snout Moths**) are less likely and would be eliminated if a photograph showing the front of the head were available and it turned out that the palps were not elongate and projecting.

Comment: Arthur, I've noticed you've provided a handful of species ID answers lately. All of your answers are short, lack references/support, lack photos, and typically don't try to identify beyond the family level. These answers will all likely get downvoted as they do not represent the effort or specificity that are typically expected on this site (and desired by the asker). Please start expanding upon your answers or simply providing your posts as comments instead. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for a guide to writing good answers on this site. Thanks!